# Custom bins in choropleth Plotly map

Tags: python, plotly, choropleth

I would like to create a global map with my data using `choropleth plotly`. The problem is that my data has a range of several orders of magnitude differences. I tried plotting the data using a log scale but it does not create the desired results. I would like to create custom bins or ticks in my data. How would I do this? I gave it several attempts spending two days on this but no results.

This is my code:

```
fig = px.choropleth(df, locations='value', color=np.log10(df['value'].replace(0, np.nan)),
                    color_continuous_scale="YlOrRd",
                    # range_color=(0, 12),
                    )

fig.update_layout(coloraxis_colorbar=dict(
    title="Value",
    tickvals=[1E-22,1E-10,1E-9,1E-8,1E-7,4.3E-06],
    ticktext=["<E-10","1E-10", "1E-9","1E-8","1E-7","4.3E-06"],
    # lenmode="pixels", len=100,
))

fig.show()
```

This is what I want to have:
[image: what I want]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `go.Choropleth` with `colorscale` and `colorbar` works:

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Choropleth(
    locations=df["Country Code"].values, 
    z=df["Log Value"].values,
    colorscale=your_colorscale,
    ],
    colorbar=dict(
        tick0=18,  # start
        dtick=2    # step
    )
))

fig.show()
```

`your_colorscale` should be in this format:

```py
your_colorscale = [
    # Let first 10% (0.1) of the values have color rgb(0, 0, 0)
    [0, "rgb(0, 0, 0)"],
    [0.1, "rgb(0, 0, 0)"],

    # Let values between 10-20% of the min and max of z
    # have color rgb(20, 20, 20)
    [0.1, "rgb(20, 20, 20)"],
    [0.2, "rgb(20, 20, 20)"],

    # Values between 20-30% of the min and max of z
    # have color rgb(40, 40, 40)
    [0.2, "rgb(40, 40, 40)"],
    [0.3, "rgb(40, 40, 40)"]
    
    # And so on
]
```

Note that values 0.1 and 0.2 appear twice. Looks like it's important to make a discrete color bar, not continuous.

---

Another option is to split data in bins and then plot it as a categorical variable.

You cat split values into bins by using `pd.cut`

```py
df["cut"] = pd.cut(df["variable"].values, your_bins, include_lowest=True)
df["cut"].cat.categories = ["name1", "name2", "name3", "name4", "name5"]
```

After that, plot your map, but replace `color_continuous_scale` with `color_discrete_map`

```py
color_discrete_map = dict(zip(
    ["name1", "name2", "name3", "name4", "name5"],
    colors_for_categories
))

fig = px.choropleth(
    df, locations="Country Code", color="cut",
    color_discrete_map=color_discrete_map
)
fig.show()
```

But that looks more complicated.

Comment: This is great, thanks. I am using the second option you gave and that works perfectly. The only thing I would like to change is to change the legend into the same as the picture I uploaded, rather than the discreet dots. Would you know how to do this?